# "wheel" event is being fired infinitly and crashing my website

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./Skill.css";
import { Fade } from "react-reveal";
function Skill({ name, color }) {
  const [style, setStyle] = useState({ borderBottom: `4px solid ${color}` });
  
  window.addEventListener("wheel", () => {
    let scroll = window.scrollY;
    console.log(scroll);
    if (scroll >= 1300) {
      setStyle({
        animation: "load 2s ease-out",
        display: "block",
        borderBottom: `4px solid ${color}`,
      });
    }
  });
  return (
    <>
      <div className="skill">
        <Fade bottom>
          <div className="Skill__logo">
            <img
              className="logo__img"
              src="./images/html-5-logo-svgrepo-com.svg"
              alt=""
            />
          </div>
          <div className="skills__about">
            <div className="skillitem">
              <div className="skill__set">
                <div className="skill__Name" style={{ color: color }}>
                  {name}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div style={style} className="loading__skill"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Fade>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Skill;
```

Here is my code and I dunno for some reason the wheel event is firing infinitely and crashing my application
kindly if somebody can tell me what is the issue

I dunno for some reason the wheel event is firing infinitely and crashing my application
kindly if somebody can tell me what is the issue

Comment: Even if you were problem-free, you should have a debounce on that listener just as a conservative measure. Would you actually need such high-frequency polling? Better to debounce by say 200-500ms or something, and keep performance stable. Finally, even if your machine may behave smoothly, some other client may behave differently (e.g. lower-performance device).

Comment: Hi, if my answer helped resolve your question, would you mind accepting it? Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

When `setStyle` inside the `wheel` event listener callback is called - the `Skill` component is refreshed which then invokes `window.addEventListener("wheel", () => {` again; adding another callback to the `window` and because `wheel` was what was called initially it is called again, hence repeating this loop infinitely.

This can be fixed easily by adding the logic that is only meant to be getting triggered by the first render inside a `useEffect` hook which has the second parameter as `[]`, like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("wheel", () => {
    let scroll = window.scrollY;
    console.log(scroll);
    if (scroll >= 1300) {
      setStyle({
        animation: "load 2s ease-out",
        display: "block",
        borderBottom: `4px solid ${color}`,
      });
    }
  });
}, []);
```

The above however is a quick workaround to your solution. `window` based properties should realistically be controlled in the parent-most component of the application to avoid global variable pollution and maintainability the event listeners that are exerted on the application in a cohesive manner.

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be because when you scroll, the wheel event is fired many times. You can try to apply a debouncing script.

```js
// ...more code
function debounce(func, timeout = 300){
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => { func.apply(this, args); }, timeout);
  };
}
 window.addEventListener("wheel", debounce(() => {
    let scroll = window.scrollY;
    console.log(scroll);
    if (scroll >= 1300) {
      setStyle({
        animation: "load 2s ease-out",
        display: "block",
        borderBottom: `4px solid ${color}`,
      });
    }
  }));
// ...more code
```

The example limits it to firing every `300` milliseconds, or every `0.3` of a second.

Comment: There's one problem to it that if I continuously scroll like with my trackpad, this will still not work as the trackpad hasn't come to the rest from its inertial deltaY

Answer (score 0):

Remember, every time you set state or change a prop, a render cycle is incurred. And, in your component, at **every render cycle you are setting a listener on the `scroll` event that you never unset**.  *Furthermore,* one of the actions in your listener handler is to set state, which will invoke another render, which creates yet another listener, to invoke another render-- you can see where this is approaching an infinite loop-like situation.

What you should do is use the `useState` hook, to set your handler on the initial render only, and then return a function that unsets the listener on the unmount of the component:

```
// define handleWheel outside your function, or with `useCallback` to set a persistent reference
const handleWheel = () => {
  let scroll = window.scrollY;
  console.log(scroll);
  if (scroll >= 1300) {
    setStyle({
      animation: "load 2s ease-out",
      display: "block",
      borderBottom: `4px solid ${color}`,
    });
  }
}


// later, in your component:
useState(() => {
  window.addEventListener("wheel", handleWheel);
  return () => window.removeEventListener("wheel", handleWheel); // to be called at unmount of component
}, []); // empty array ensures it will be called only at first render
```

Answer (score 0):

So many good answers but nobody considered a way to avoid re-render. So I am giving you a different approach. `Your window.addEventListener("wheel")` is getting called when you scroll using the wheel and when the scrollY goes beyond 1300 a style is set with the state. This causes a re-render of the component. If you scroll further, the component will keep re-rendering. I assume you want to apply a style when `scroll >= 1300` and revert it back when we scroll to the top.

If we use a `useRef()` to hold a value that detects whether the required state change has occurred, then we can avoid a whole lot of re-render by not setting the style again and again as we scroll. The value change of `ref` won't re-render the component. Only the state changes will.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

So let me try to give a working code example,

https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-dawn-ureml7?file=/src/App.js

You may also use `React.Memo()` and pass a comparison function to avoid any re-render on the continuous scroll event, style set.